# onsen ui (2 rc5) ons-bottom-toolbar angular template TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I tried some thing like this:

```
<ons-bottom-toolbar>{{ 'show this text in bottom toolbar' }}</ons-bottom-toolbar>
```

and I get this error

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'nodeValue' of undefined
    at interpolateFnWatchAction (angular.js:8878)
    at interpolateFnWatcher (angular.js:11388)
    at watchGroupAction (angular.js:15873)
    at constantListener (angular.js:14735)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:16203)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:16467)
    at done (angular.js:10852)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:11050)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:10991)
```

It seems that onsen bottom toolbar doesn't accept any binding.
or may be I missed something.

#### Update:

This error just showed on GoogleChroum (Ubuntu desktop and android) latest version.

Comment: I think this works fine https://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/wWwmZZ 
Perhaps the error is in your controllers?

Comment: @FranDios if using templates you will see the problem https://jsfiddle.net/a3t3j0oz/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually this was a [bug](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/1426) in OnsenUI which is fixed (thanks to [Onsen](https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI) team especially [Andreas Argelius](https://github.com/argelius)) and will release in a week.